# Probability Theory (Geometric)

Tags: probability

A certain type of item produced by a factory has a 6% chance of being defective. Draw a random sample until you get the first defective. Let XX be the number of items that are drawn.

Find P(X=2).

I think this is a Poisson Distribution problem and I use the formula P(X=x) = e^−λ*λ^x/x! and get p = P(X=2) = 0.0017, but it seems to be incorrect, can anyone explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would use the geometric distribution. Try that. I get $5.64\%$

Comment: @callculus, for geometric, I use P(X=2) = (1-p)^x*p = (0.94^2)*0.06 = 0.053016, but still incorrect, how did you get 5.64%?

Comment: $X=2$ means that you draw 2 items only. First one non-defective and then one defective item. So the pdf is $P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$ for for $k = 1, 2, 3, ....$

Comment: @callculus, I see the point, much appreciated!

Comment: It pleases me that it is all clear now. You´re welcome.